# Does anyone knows what wordpress theme is this?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone knows what is the wordpress theme of this site?
http://www.ana7aml.com/
Thank you all in advance?

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom-built theme. You can check the theme's info on its style.css file: http://www.ana7aml.com/wp-content/themes/theme4/style.css

Answer (score 0):

you can see full info about wordpress theme and plugins a website uses with [wpthemedetector](http://www.wpthemedetector.com/) just enter or copy the website URL in the box and hit the green button :)